# Calculate position after adding an angle

Tags: python-3.x, math, coordinates, angle

I am trying to make a calculator-like program that has a specific starting point and I want to take a point on a canvas (I get the x and y of this point). Now, I want to from the `starting_point` add 30 on the angle and calculate the point on the canvas (like a circle and just change it's position).

I don't have any code about it.

I know in maths that I have to think of a circle and calculate it's position on the circle but I am not sure about how to do this in programming. I'd like if you could show me in how to do it in preferably python, or in another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a sample code:

```py
import math

x = int(input('x position: '))
y = int(input('y position: '))
a = - math.radians(int(input('angle to add: ')))

new_x = math.cos(a)*x - math.sin(a)*y
new_y = math.sin(a)*x + math.cos(a)*y

print(f'new point: {new_x} {new_y}')
```